# visualstudio code C++ terminal for output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

When debugging a C++ application on linux using, VisualStudio Code, an instance of an external terminal window is opened, and the applications console appears on this window.

This is a bit inconvenient because I have to change windows to see the output when debugging.

Is it possible to have the output to appear in a "pane" like the built in terminal appears (like the one started by CTRL-`)? If so how can this be done?

I have tried changing the launch file's "externalConsole" from true to false but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal).

View > Toggle Integrated Terminal

Comment: I believe that is the terminal window. I can run that using the short cut CTRL-` but the only way I cannot get the output from the launcher to appear in a window like that. If I run the executable from the terminal, I do get the output but no breakpoints, variables, other debugging features are available.

Comment: Is there any news on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In `launch.json` set  `"externalConsole": false,`.
Then the output goes to the `Debug Console`.

But instead of things looking like:

> Hello World!

It will show up as:

> @"Hello World!\r\n"

I have read that they still work in proper terminal support for the terminal inside VSCode. I think that also explains why it defaults now to the external terminal.